# Insulin and leptin action on Anorexigenic Neurons in Hypothalamus?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, neurophysiology, cell-signaling, hypothalamus

Receptors for Insulin are present on liver, adipose tissue and muscles. In addition, there are Insulin Receptors present in arcuate nucleus of hypothalamus, which influences anorexogenic neurons through IRS2 and PI-3K signaling. They also causes the inhibition of Food intake by increasing the expression of POMC, and cleaving its protein to alpha melanocortio stimulating hormone (αMSH). This is however the same response produced by the release of "LEPTIN" that act on anorexogenic neurons, and stop eating behavior - similarly as insulin by producing (αMSH).

My question is: why insulin goes to brain and produce this effect when their was Leptin available to do the same task? What is the significance of Insulin action here?

Comment: This question is identical in nature if not in subject to [this one](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/46399/5198). I'm a bit puzzled. Can the body not have several pathways for achieving a "goal"? Why, to you, should this overlap *not exist*, since clearly it does, and we seem to be surviving in spite (or because) of it?

Comment: receptors for insulin are present in many more tissues than just liver, adipose and muscle... the insulin receptor is expressed in numerous tissues throughout the body (as well as the leptin receptor - it's not just expressed in the CNS or adipose tissue)... different tissues may express the same receptor but the tissue effect can be very different (as well as overlapping with other hormones).